# Unity. Настройка графики и управления перед запуском игры

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу добавить такую возможность в свою игру, но не могу найти информацию об этом, да я даже не знаю как оно называется правильно. Помогите найти информацию на эту тему, ссылки, гайды, что нибудь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На **данный момент** это возможно сделать только на версии Unity **ниже** `2019.3.x`.

Включается это достаточно просто:

Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Resolution and Presentation -> Display Resolution Dialog

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]